# Largest positive integer $k$ such that $\mu(n+r)=0$ for all $1\leq r\leq k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the largest positive integer $k$, such  that $\mu(n+r)=0$ for all $1\leq r\leq k$ where $r,n$ are positive integers.

As far as I could make out, we need to find out the maximum range(if nay) of numbers where each has a square divisor.

I have gone through the theory of square-free numbers [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) and [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), but could not proceed much.

Comment: By now, over a month on the website, you should know that (i) you will get better answers if you present context, and you explain what you have done or where you are stuck; and (ii) that many people find it at least mildly annoying to have requests for help phrased as orders.

Comment: what does miu mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function

Comment: Depends on $n$ in a chaotic way, usually smallish, but can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such largest positive integer. Given $k$ primes, by the Chinese remainder theorem we can find a number $m$ that has remainders $1$ through $k$ with respect to their squares. Then $m-k$ through $m-1$ all have square divisors.

Comment: Just beat me - very nice. +1

Comment: Are you saying we can always find integral solutions of $a_{r+1}p^2_{r+1}-a_rp^2_r=1$ for any range 1≤r≤n for different primes $p_r$ for any positive integral value of n?

Comment: @lab: Do you know the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)? It's not just about two primes at a time; we can find numbers with arbitrary remainders for arbitrary coprime integers (e.g. prime powers).

Comment: Agreed & accepted.